# Using logarithms to simplify fractional limits to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln f(x)}{\ln g(x)} = +\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = +\infty$$

Is this true? If it is, does anyone have any tips on how to prove it? I feel like it's a simple matter of the nature of the logarithmic function, but I'm just not sure how to set up the argument.

Edit: I missed some edge cases in my original question. In order to avoid them, I also know that as $x \to \infty$, $f(x), g(x) \to +\infty$. Given this, is the statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.  If $g(x) \to 1, \ln (g(x)) \to 0$ which can make the first fraction diverge even if $f(x)$ is constant.  Then the ratio without the logs goes to the value of $f(x)$.

For example, let $g(x)=1+\frac 1x, f(x)=3$.  Then $\frac {\ln f(x)}{\ln g(x)}=\frac {\ln 3}{\ln(1+\frac 1x)}\approx x\ln(3)\to +\infty$, but $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac 3{1+\frac 1x}\to 3$

Added:  The only problem comes when $g(x) \to 1$.  If you can show $g(x) \gt k \gt 1$ you have $\frac 1{\ln (g(x))} \gt \frac 1{\ln (k)}$ so the fact that the limit of the logs is infinite means the limit of the log of $f(x)$ is infinite.  The ratio of the functions then has to go to infinity as well.

Comment: Thank you! I clearly missed some edge cases here. In the problem that I am dealing with, as $x \to \infty$ both $f,g \to \infty$, as I am comparing growth rates. Do you have any ideas for putting together a quick proof of it?

Comment: If $g \to \infty$ the ratio of the logs diverging is much stronger than the ratio of the functions diverging.  How much stronger depends on the form of $g$.  If $g$ is like $x$ the ratio of the logs going to infinity means that $x$ grows faster than any polynomial while the ratio of the functions  would let $f$ be $x \ln x$, for example

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log(|f|)/\log(|g|) = \infty,$ then for each $K>0$, there is some $X>0$ s.t. whenever $|x|>X$, 
$$
|\log(|f|)| > K |\log(|g|)| \implies \log(|f|) > K|\log(|f|)| \text { or } \log(|f|) < -K |\log(|g|)|.
$$
Take exponential:
$$
|f| > \mathrm e^K \exp(|\log (|g|)|)
$$
or
$$
|f| <\mathrm e^{-K}\exp(|\log (|g|)|).
$$
If $|g|>1$ for sufficiently large $x$, then
$$
|f| > \mathrm e^K |g| \text{ or } |f| < \mathrm e^{-K} |g|. 
$$
According to these, you could take $f(x) =\mathrm e^{-x}$, $g(x) =\mathrm e$ to satisfy the second case above, then $\log(f)/\log(g) = -x \to \infty$, but $f/g \to 0$.

P.S. The meaning of $\infty$ is not specified, so I take the most general definition.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I should have clarified that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x), g(x) = \infty$, as I see now it is important that they are both positive and increasing off to $\infty$. Also, I think the definition of $\infty$ I used was explicitly $+\infty$, which I should have clarified.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln f(x)}{\ln g(x)} 
= +\infty 
\Rightarrow 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} 
= +\infty
$

You need the
additional assumption that
$g(x) \to \infty$.

If
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln f(x)}{\ln g(x)} 
= +\infty 
$
then,
for any $c > 0$,
there is an $x(c)$ such that
$\frac{\ln f(x)}{\ln g(x)}
\gt c$
for $x > x(c)$.

Then
$\ln (f(x))
\gt c\ln (g(x))
$
so,
if $c > 1$
and
$g(x) \to \infty$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(f(x)/g(x))
&=\ln(f(x))-\ln(g(x))\\
&>c\ln(g(x))-\ln(g(x))\\
&=(c-1)\ln(g(x))\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x)/g(x) \to \infty$.